# How to contribute to selenium webdriver souce code of java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am working as a QA-Automation for a company. I wanted to contribute to selenium webdriver v3.0.2. I started working on it.
Forked the project from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium
Cloned the selenium source
Now I want to setup and run the sample tests in the project and I want to configure to my eclipse. I am just stuck this point. It would be very much helpful if anyone shares the solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't specify any specific problem... please read [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) before contributing.

Comment: I was familiar with eclipse IDE and I just planned to configure selenium source code to eclipse. But after adding the dependent jars I was getting an error Description Resource Path Location Type Archive for required library: 'D:/selenium_source/java/third_party/all_java_jars/commons-fileupload-1.2.2-src.jar' in project 'client' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file client Build path Build Path Problem. Finally, I thought of switching to Intellij since the source is written and compiled it that IDE

Comment: @Moshisho I am getting an error Error:(22, 23) java: package org.apache.http does not exist. Can you please help me to configure this?

Comment: See this link https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Building-WebDriver can't help you without sufficient details. Maybe it requires a different question. In order to contribute to such a major project you really need to know what your doing and first read ALL the information in those links . I suggest you first clone it, add the Java webdriver project to a playground project and play with it a little. No offense:)